# Ghost Data in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I've got a CakePHP save method that is saving multiple entries per one save request.  I have *no* idea why -- my AppModel doesn't have any special functions, nor does my AppController.  My Controller and Model are pretty basic.  Here's what I have:

**BalanceSheet Model**

```
<?php
class BalanceSheet extends AppModel {
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Simulation' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'simulation_id',
        )
    );
}
?>
```

**BalanceSheets Controller**

```
<?php
class BalanceSheetsController extends AppController {
    function generate($simulation_id) {
        $data = array(
            'BalanceSheet' => array(
                'simulation_id' => $simulation_id,
                'year' => 2004
            )
        );
        $this->BalanceSheet->save($data);
    }
}
?>
```

**Database Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `balance_sheets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `simulation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `buildings_and_improvements` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=72 ;
```

When my balance sheet table is empty, and I navigate to balance_sheets/generate/10, this is the result:

[image: SQL rows]

What.  What the heck?  What's going on there?  How can I get it to just save once?

**EDIT**

Turns out my controller's being called multiple times (I'm not sure why).  I'll keep stepping through the debugger to find out what's going on.

Comment: enclose the save method, please

Comment: Just tested on CakePHP 1.3.11 and it's working here. What version are you on?

Comment: Not entirely sure what's going wrong, had a few weird things happening with different MySQL versions. You could try adding `$this->BalanceSheet->create();` before saving the record

Comment: @ajreal How do you mean?  Deizel, I'm on the same version.  :(  And Kevin, unfortunately that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh...figured it out.  It was a stylesheet declaration someone had put in the code with an incorrect relative path -- it was passing in "css" as the simulation ID, which is why the duplicate was being inserted as 0!

This was what helped me deduce it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/353493/390977):

> Check your layout for non-existent links, for example a misconfigured
>   link to favicon.ico will cause the controller action to be triggered
>   for a second time. Make sure favicon.ico points towards the webroot
>   rather than the local directory, or else requests will be generated
>   for /controller/action/favicon.ico rather than /favicon.ico - and thus
>   trigger your action.